# Firebase replacing an entire array returning "Unsupported type: __SwiftValue"

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I have a document that contains an array with the following structure:

```
"songs": [
   { "id": "asdasdasd", "votes": 1, "downVotedBy": [], "upVotedBy": ["user1"] }
]
```

When I'm trying to upvote the song using other user, after adding the user to the "upVotedBy" array, adding one to "votes" and ordering the songs based on the votes, I want to replace the entire array, so I do something like this:

```
ref.updateData([ "songs": songs ])
```

Where songs is an array containing elements of this custom class:

```
public struct SongModel: Codable {
    var id: String
    var votes: Int = 1
    var upVotedBy: [String]
    var downVotedBy: [String]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case votes
        case upVotedBy
        case downVotedBy
    }
}
```

But I get an Exception "Unsupported type: __SwiftValue"

Comment: Are you intending on replacing the entire document with an empty document? It's not clear from the question what 'songs' is - in the first snippet it appears that songs is a document or collection and each song is stored as a child value. But in the second snippet, it looks like 'songs' is in an array `[ "songs": songs ]`, not a collection or document. Perhaps if you can clarify the question and include more complete code, we can provide an answer. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution was to convert the array of SongModel to an array of dictionaries:

```
private func convertSongToDic(songs: [SongModel]) -> [Any]{
        var newSongs = [Any]()
        
        for song in songs {
            newSongs.append([
                "id": song.id,
                "votes": song.votes,
                "upVotedBy": song.upVotedBy,
                "downVotedBy": song.downVotedBy
            ])
        }
        
        return newSongs
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting your solution.